# Unable to center button

Tags: html, css

I faced a problem about getting a button to center, I tried the `text-align: center`, but it didn't work.

```css
.regis-btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cellphone">Cellphone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellphone" minlength="10" placeholder="Cellphone">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seriesnum">Series Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seriesnum" placeholder="Series Number">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn regis-btn" id="register" style="background: #FFCC00;">
           <span> Register </span>
       </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sure there's some more CSS somewhere that affects your buttons. From your code I cann see that there's a least the class *btn* assigned to your button.

Comment: @Robert class btn is from bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div class="form-group text-center"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn regis-btn" id="register" style="background: #FFCC00;"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`text-align: center` only centers the content within the element. So what you have done was to center the text within the button.

If your button is the only element in the row, wrap the button in a div instead.

I added a demo to show that it works:

```css
.btn-container {
    text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="cellphone">Cellphone Number</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellphone" minlength="10" placeholder="Cellphone">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Username</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="seriesnum">Series Number</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seriesnum" placeholder="Series Number">
   </div>
   <div class="btn-container">
       <button type="button" class="btn regis-btn" id="register" style="background: #FFCC00;">
           <span>Register</span>
       </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it's not working, is bootstrap css interfering my css??

Answer (score 2):

Use `margin: 0 auto;` and `display: block;` for button.

```css
.regis-btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cellphone">Cellphone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellphone" minlength="10" placeholder="Cellphone">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seriesnum">Series Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seriesnum" placeholder="Series Number">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn regis-btn" id="register" style="background: #FFCC00;">
                  <span>
                     Register
                  </span>
              </button>
</form>
```

Comment: i put that, but it's not working..can bootstrap css interfere the css?

Answer (score 2):

Use My code that is working very well.

```css
.regis-btn {
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;     
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="cellphone">Cellphone Number</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellphone" minlength="10" placeholder="Cellphone">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Username</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Username">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="seriesnum">Series Number</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seriesnum" placeholder="Series Number">
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
   <button type="button" class="btn regis-btn" id="register" style="background: #FFCC00;">
       <span> Register </span>
   </button>
   </div>
</form>
```